# ASP.net 2.0 dynamic Radio Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-2.0, radio-button, pageload

I need to create dynamic radio buttons in my page, and then access their values in postback

I create the buttons using the following code:

```
foreach (Answer answer in question.Answers)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
    radioButton.Text = answer.Text;
    radioButton.GroupName = question.Id.ToString();
    radioButton.ID = question.Id + "_" + answer.Id;

    TableRow answerRow = new TableRow();
    TableCell answerCell = new TableCell();
    TableCell emptyCell = new TableCell();

    emptyCell.ColumnSpan = 2;

    answerCell.Controls.Add(radioButton);
    answerRow.Cells.Add(emptyCell);
    answerRow.Cells.Add(answerCell);

    table.Rows.Add(answerRow);
}
```

In the post back I try to access the radio buttons using their create ID:

```
foreach (Answer answer in question.Answers)
{
    RadioButton currentAnswer = Page.FindControl(question.Id + "_" + answer.Id) as RadioButton;
    if (currentAnswer != null) // Damn this null
    {
        if(currentAnswer.Checked)
        {
            answers[questionCounter] = answer;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        allQuestionsAnswered = false;
    }
}
```

But it seems that the find method is never finding the answer.

Please let me know when to use the above code.
In the load method, in the preload, in the button click of the submit method.

It seems that I always get null and never find the control.

Answer (score 1):

Your control is not found because the FindControl method doesn't go down the control hierarchy, it only searches in the top level controls. You have to call it recursively for the controls in your page.

Comment: What is the control argument I should pass to that method?

Comment: You can wrap your page controls in a PlaceHolder and pass that PlaceHolder in the method. You can also do a foreach(Control c in Page.Controls){ Control myControl = FindControlRecursive(c, id)); if(myControl != null) {//Here it is! Your control!}}

Comment: I was looking into this issue all morning, if the same controls are not reloaded in the page load, I cannot fetch their value from the button click event. How do I solve this problem, do I load them and then remove them?

Comment: You generate your controls dynamically, right? Then you have to recreate the controls OnInit, then ASP.NET binds the viewstate values to the controls, and then you can access their values in your button click. If you don't recreate the controls OnInit, ASP.NET cannot "attach" the values to the controls and you will never have the latest selections in those controls. Confusing?

Comment: Its confusing, Y isn't there a value containing all the data sent back from the client so I can iterate through that. I checked the response object but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: You can always try Request.Form["YourControlId"]. But I recommend you to generate the controls you have in your foreach statement OnInit, then everything should work ok.